# momentJs validity check is wrong

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I have a special parser in my application that can parse relative and absolute times.

The parser breaks when moment recognize a relative time type as a valid absolute time.

How come:

```
let instance = moment('now-1d', 'YYYYMMDD')
instance.isValid()
```

returns `true` with date `Mon Jan 01 0001 00:00:00 GMT+0049`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [strict parsing](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/)

```js
let instance = moment('now-1d', 'YYYYMMDD',true)

console.log(instance.isValid())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```